# If/else event (changing file path) not changing when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

[image: rhythm A and rhythm B with checkbox]

On my website, a user chooses 2 rhythms from among 100 different choices (each of which has a unique id. In the image above, as you can see, the user has selected rhythm 2.5 and rhythm 5.8.

There is an audio file associated with each rhythm, which can be played by clicking the play button.

Actually, there are TWO audio files associated with each rhythm -- a straight version and a swing version.

When the user clicks the "swing it" checkbox, I want the swing version to play.

Otherwise, I want the straight version to play. The names of the straight and swing audio files are identical (`2.5.mp3`, for example), but the straight version is called at `audio/2.5.mp3` and the swing version is called at `audio/swing/2.5.mp3`.

I've looked at many SO posts, but my code's not working. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="playRow">               
    <div class="rhythms_AandB">
        <div class="currentSelection">
            <div class="playFeatured"><audio id="playA" preload='none'></audio>
                <button class="featuredAudio" onclick="document.getElementById('playA').play()">&#x25b6;</button></div> 
            <div class="selectedLabelA" id="currentLabelA">A</div>
            <div class="selectedRhythm currentRhythm_A" id="currentRhythm_A"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="currentSelection">
            <div class="playFeatured"><audio id="playB" preload='none'></audio>
                <button class="featuredAudio" onclick="document.getElementById('playB').play()">&#x25b6;</button></div> 
            <div class="selectedLabelB" id="currentLabelB">B</div>
            <div class="selectedRhythm currentRhythm_B" id="currentRhythm_B"></div>
        </div>
</div>  
<div class="swingRow">
        <input type="checkbox" name="swingBox" id="swingBox" class="css-checkbox" /><label for="swingBox" class="css-label">Swing it <a href="" id="swing-tooltip" data-tipped-options="position: 'bottom'">(?)</a></label>
        </div>  
</div>
```

And here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var activeRhythmA = document.getElementById('currentLabelA');
var activeRhythmB = document.getElementById('currentLabelB');
function swingIt() {
    if(document.getElementById('swingBox').checked) {
    $('#playA').html("<source src='audio/swing/" + activeRhythmA + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/swing/" + activeRhythmA + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />"); $('#playA').load();
    $('#playB').html("<source src='audio/swing/" + activeRhythmB + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/swing/" + activeRhythmB + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />"); $('#playB').load();
    }
    else {
    $('#playA').html("<source src='audio/" + activeRhythmA + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/" + activeRhythmA + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />"); $('#playA').load();
    $('#playB').html("<source src='audio/" + activeRhythmB + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/" + activeRhythmB + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />"); $('#playB').load();    
    }
};
});
```

Comment: `activeRhythmA` will return an `HTMLAudioElement`, I seriously doubt this is what you need. Instead, try to set `...audio/swing/" + currentLabelA +".mp3...``

Comment: @Kaiido, thanks for the advice. I'll try this.

Comment: I tried this, @Kaiido, but it didn't work. Can you point me in a direction to help me better understand how to convert the DOM element to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are only checking for the checkbox when the page is loaded. You need to apply a click handler for the checkbox. It also appears that you are selecting name of the file incorrectly, but I may be misunderstanding how it is supposed to work. Here is an attempt based on what you have provided:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  // Side note, this can be simplified to $(function () {
    $('#swingBox').click(function() {
        var swingPath = this.checked ? 'swing/' : '';
        $.each(['A', 'B'], function(i, label) {
            var activeRhythm = $('#currentLabel' + label).text();
            $('#play' + label)
                .html('<source src="audio/' + swingPath + activeRhythm + '.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /><source src="audio/' + swingPath + activeRhythm + '.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />')
                .load();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this isn't working for me, but I sure love how it looks :) I'm new to js and your answer has lots of syntax new to me... so there's lots for me to learn in order to even understand your answer. Thanks so much for your time... I'll see if I can implement this properly.

Comment: @jennykat, I think I misunderstood where you were storing you value. I've updated my answer to use the original ids that you were using. Maybe that will fix it. You didn't provide any info on how the track is being selected, so if you are still having an issue after this change, providing some of that background may help.

Comment: it WORKS! I'm super-psyched... and I'm going to use your code as a jumping-off point for learning. Thanks SO much!

Comment: @jennykat Awesome, glad I could help you with your problem and glad I could help you learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

You never call the swingIt() function. You need to call it whenever the "Swing It" box is checked. Try:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
var activeRhythmA = document.getElementById('currentLabelA');
var activeRhythmB = document.getElementById('currentLabelB');
function swingIt() {
    if(document.getElementById('swingBox').checked) {
    $('#playA').html("<source src='audio/swing/" + activeRhythmA + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/swing/" + activeRhythmA + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />"); $('#playA').load();
    $('#playB').html("<source src='audio/swing/" + activeRhythmB + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/swing/" + activeRhythmB + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />"); $('#playB').load();
    }
    else {
    $('#playA').html("<source src='audio/" + activeRhythmA + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/" + activeRhythmA + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />"); $('#playA').load();
    $('#playB').html("<source src='audio/" + activeRhythmB + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='audio/" + activeRhythmB + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />"); $('#playB').load();    
    }
};

$('#swingBox').change(swingIt);
  
});
```

Note that as rdubya points out, your activeRhythmA and activeRhythmB variable isn't doing what you want it to do yet - it's currently a DOM element but you're treating it as a string. Consider hard-coding in one of the URLs until you have the checkbox logic working.

Comment: hey! When I hard-code the rhythm in, it works! So my problem is just to call the number of the rhythm correctly. THANKS!!!

Comment: I'll ask you what I asked above... can you give me a hint as to how to convert a DOM element to a string? I thought that's what I was doing by setting it as a variable, but obviously I'm new to this. :) Thanks!

Comment: activeRhythmA is supposed to be a number like 2.5, right? As it stands, it looks like that isn't already anywhere in the HTML. If you had, for example,             `<div class="selectedLabelA" id="currentLabelA">2.5</div>`, then you could do `var activeRhythmA = $('#currentLabelA').text();` or `var activeRhythmA = document.getElementById('currentLabelA').innerHTML;`

Comment: the twist is that the number is called dynamically, by another piece of code, because the user can change the current rhythm at any time. I tried adding .innerHTML, but it doesn't work. Hmmm. I'll keep thinking. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Can you show what the HTML will look like after it's called dynamically? Put the variable declarations inside the swingIt() function instead of inside just $(document).ready(). Also, consider doing something like `alert($('#currentLabelA').text());` or `console.log($('#currentLabelA').text());` to help figure out what value is being used.

Comment: Thanks, @TAGraves. I've never used the console, so this will give me some good experience. rdubya's code works, and I'm going to try to make your suggestions work, too, so I know two ways to do it.